# What type of object is the Event.Owner property?

Tags: relationships

I am struggling to understand the nuances of related fields.

In my VF page for Events, I can access properties of the event owner like so: `Event.Owner.Name`, and `Event.Owner.Type`. Because of this, I assumed that the `Owner` property on the `Event` object was an instance of `User`.

However, in the extension controller that backs this VF page, when I try to set `Event.Owner` to an instance of a `User` object, I get a compile error: `Illegal assignment from User to Name`. This implies that the `Owner` property on `Event` is actually of type `Name`.

To further complicate things, the Developer Console suggests fields from the `User` object when I type `Event.Owner.`.

So the question is, what is `Event.Owner`? And if it's `User`, how can I set it to an instance of `User`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owner on the Event, Account, Opportunity, and other standard Objects is a polymorphic field (IIRC). When referencing the relationship you use `Owner.Name` etc like you have. However when setting the ID of the Owner you use `OwnerID` instead.

> In the past, Owner was a troublesome relationship field. Most
>   relationship fields support cross-object formula references to access
>   related parent data, but until the Summer 13 release, this has not
>   been the case with Owner. Almost every sObject has this field, and in
>   many, Owner can only be a user. But in Lead, Case, and custom
>   sObjects, Owner is either a user or a queue. This means at the data
>   model level, the field is polymorphic and can contain either a user or
>   a group id value.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/cross-object-owner-fields-a-powerful-new-formula-option.html

Comment: [It doesn't look like the field is polymorphic](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_activities.htm), but you are right on to use `OwnerId` to set the value

Comment: In most cases name type is polymorphic. See link in sdfcfox post. In case of event it just looks to a single object

Comment: I am able to, and currently am, using `Event.OwnerId` to set the owner to the user that I want. But when I set `OwnerId`, the properties `Event.Owner.Name` are not updated to the values that would be associated to the Id that has been set until after the next save/retrieve of the event. Is there a way to "refresh" this `Name` object (ie have it repopulate based on what the OwnerId is currently set to)?

Comment: After doing DML then requery. If you have the ID there are plenty of ways to get the name. In your code

Comment: Even though owner isn't polymorphic for Event, I wonder if the way that `sObject` treats that field is as if it is (or because it is in some objects, it has special rules for all objects). But then, why wouldn't it let you assign a user, instead of just the ID? Can you post some code examples @ChrisPayne of what specifically you are doing? It might be adding this in as a user-story or bug. (By the way thanks for quoting my first blog post ever on the salesforce dev blogs, Eric. :-)

Comment: @Peter - I think it "IS" polymorphic as the Name type specifically states it is. Difference is that it can only be lookup to User. Just like some can lookup to Queue and some can't. So Name type (object) is polymorphic but in the case of Event it only allows One type of object to lookup to. At least that is my take on it....If in the future Event can be owned by something other than user then Owner field would not have to change just the rules that limits what it looks up to.....and your welcome :)

Comment: `After doing DML then requery. If you have the ID there are plenty of ways to get the name`. Do you mean requery to retrieve the event @Eric? What if I'm creating an event and do not have an ID for this new event yet?

Comment: @Peter: My extension controller has a piece of logic in the constructor that pre-populates assigned to based on a couple of factors. In the front end, I am displaying text along the lines of: `This event will be assigned to Event.Owner.Name`

Comment: @ChrisPayne - Why do you need the Name? Posting a new question related to this along with code will help us asset you. Also, please accept one of the answers here so others searching for a similar question can find ones with answers

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_name.htm) type. A Name type looks kind of like a User, but it's not. It has a limited set of fields that are common across many different objects. Notably, it doesn't include custom User fields or other things you might normally be able to do with a User. Normally, you can only set a Name reference through a query or by some JSON manipulation. The fields inside the Name object are all read-only.